# Use of undefined constant http_code - assumed I do not understand

Tags: php

So i have 2 files. It is trying to crawl on a website and pull information onto the page. The code seems fine but when I run on my php error log i get: Use of undefined constant http_code - assumed 'http_code' in /www/craw/httpcurl.php on line 57

httpcurl.php:

```
<?php

define('EMAIL_PATTERN', '/([\s]*)([_a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*([ ]+|)@([ ]+|)([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+([a-zA-Z]{2,}))([\s]*)/i');

interface HttpScraper
{
  public function parse($body, $head);
}

class Scraper implements HttpScraper
{

public function parse($body, $head) {
   if ($head == 200) {
    $p = preg_match_all(EMAIL_PATTERN, $body, $matches);
        if ($p) {
            foreach($matches[0] as $emails) {
                echo "<pre>";
                print_r($emails);  
                echo "<pre>";
            }
        }
    }
}
}

class HttpCurl {
protected $_cookie, $_parser, $_timeout;
private $_ch, $_info, $_body, $_error;

public function __construct($p = null) {
    if (!function_exists('curl_init')) {
        throw new Exception('cURL not enabled!');
    }  
    $this->setParser($p);
}

public function get($url) {
    return $this->request($url);
}

protected function request($url) {
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 5);    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $this->_body = curl_exec($ch);
    $this->_info  = curl_getinfo($ch);
    $this->_error = curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $this->runParser($this->_body, $this->getStatus());               
}

public function getStatus() {
    return $this->_info[http_code];
}

public function getHeader() {
    return $this->_info;
}

public function getBody() {
    return $this->_body;
}

public function __destruct() {
}  

public function setParser($p)   {
    if ($p === null || $p instanceof HttpScraper || is_callable($p))   
        $this->_parser = $p;
}

public function runParser($content, $header)    {
    if ($this->_parser !== null)
    {
        if ($this->_parser instanceof HttpScraper)
            $this->_parser->parse($content, $header);
        else
            call_user_func($this->_parser, $content, $header);
    }
}  
}

?>
```

test.php:
Note: I put google.com as an example since I am searching another website with many results.

```
<?php

include 'httpcurl.php';

$target = "http://google.com/";

$up = new Scraper;
$test = new HttpCurl($up);

$test->get($target);

?>
```

Comment: The correct way with associative arrays is to use single-quote: `$this->_info['http_code'];` Without single-quotes, php interpret `http_code` as constant: if there is not a constant named `http_code`, php use `'http_code'`, but if this constant exists, you have unexpected result.

Comment: see http://docs.php.net/language.types.array#language.types.array.donts